# Most direct usage of flatmap

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

I've written a `map` and a `flatmap` function, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to see how the flatmap function works as a standalone. Here are my two definitions:

```
(define (map function lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      ; if we have reached the end of the list, return an empty list
      ; this essentially terminates the list that we are adding below with the cons
      nil
      ; we do a cons -- with the scalar produced by the function call on the current element
      ;                 and the list proceduced by passing the rest of the elements again to the map function
     (cons (function (car lst)) (map function (cdr lst)))))
```

```
(define (flatmap function lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      nil
      ; really the only difference here is we do an append instead of a cons
      (append (function (car lst)) (flatmap function (cdr lst)))))
```

And to call `map` is quite easy, I just pass it a function that accepts a single argument (list element):

```
(map (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(1 2 3 4 5))
; (1 4 9 16 25)
```

However, I'm having a hard time coming up with a sample input/function that I can pass directly to the `flatmap` function to see how it works. What would be an example or two that would demonstrate how it works directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function that accepts a single argument and returns a list will do. Here's a variation of the function you used to demonstrate `map`.

```
(flatmap (lambda (x) (list x (* x x))) '(1 2 3 4 5))
; (1 1 2 4 3 9 4 16 5 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples:

```
;;; flattening a list by one-level
(flatmap (lambda (p) p) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
;(1 2 3 4 5 6)
(flatmap (lambda (p) p) '((1 2 (3 4) 5) (6 7 8)))
; (1 2 (3 4) 5 6 7 8)
```

```
;;; Map-and-flatten a list at once
(flatmap
    (lambda (p) (cons (* 2 (car p)) 
                      (list (* 2(cadr p))) )) 
    '((1 2) (3 4)))
; (2 4 6 8)
; Or could be done with a combination of the two which reads more simply:
(map (lambda (x) (* x 2)) 
     (flatmap (lambda (p) p) '((1 2) (3 4))))
; (2 4 6 8)
;; Possible to do something like (flatmap (lambda (x) (map... ?) to accomplish same?
```

Though most of the above just use the `lambda (p) p` identity which seems pretty useless overall I'm guessing...

And maybe an actually useful one to recursively flatten a list:

```
(define (flat lst)
  (flatmap (lambda (x) (if (pair? x) (flat x) (list x))) lst))

(flat '(1 2 3 (1 (2 3 (5 5 5) 4) 3)))
; (1 2 3 1 2 3 5 5 5 4 3)
```

Comment: When the function is `(lambda (p) p)` you're using `flatmap` to reimplement `append`, but it uses `append` in the definition of `flatmap`. A bit circular....

Comment: @Barmar yea, my examples suck...I was sort of typing up my examples as I was writing them in racket.